# How to load data at launching Chrome App?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

What's the best practice of loading data at launching Chrome App?

The landing page of my Chrome App is dependent on some configuration data, which I've stored in the chrome local storage. However, reading chrome local storage is an asynchronous process. Hence, after the App has launched, there is a period of time when the landing page doesn't show correctly.

To avoid this blank time (due to the asynchronous process of reading local storage), I'm thinking about reading data at background JS. However, I haven't googled out what's the best practice to do it.

Anybody has any comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just listen to the onLaunched event

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
// load your data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one piece of helpful suggestion I've got from the Google Group. Share here so that someone with the same problem might refer to it:

You can read from chrome.storage in the background page and open the window when the data is ready. However, the user experience might be even worse, because instead of the incorrect landing page, you have no user feedback at all.

The usual (and easy to implement) solution is to show your landing page with some visual feedback during data loading, like a spinning wheel with a "Loading" label. If you UI really requires the data to show up, you can add this visual indicator as an opaque div on top of the whole window.

Some people use splash screens, but I don't think it adds to the user experience.